# How to count rows with the same consecutive values

Tags: sql-server

here is my table:

```
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-----+
|  ID | tFK |  schedDate  |  complDate  | res |
+=====+=====+=============+=============+=====+
|  1  |  2  | 2018-02-01  | 2018-02-01  |  2  |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-----+
|  2  |  2  | 2018-02-02  | 2018-02-02  |  2  |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-----+
|  3  |  2  | 2018-02-03  | 2018-02-03  |  2  |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-----+
|  4  |  2  | 2018-02-04  | 2018-02-04  |  3  |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-----+
|  5  |  2  | 2018-02-05  | 2018-02-05  |  2  |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-----+
|  6  |  2  | 2018-02-06  | 2018-02-06  |  2  |
+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+-----+
```

I want to only count if tFK has been entered with the same result as the same tFK previously, no matter what date, Here is my syntax so far but its not the output I want. 
How do I add a 'CONSECUTIVE' criteria to my query?

```
SELECT [taskFK],COUNT([result]) resultCount
FROM [cil].[cil].[schedule]
where scheduledDate between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-22'
AND completionDate IS NOT NULL
AND result=2
GROUP BY taskFK
HAVING COUNT([result]) > @variable
ORDER BY taskFK
```

EDIT:

this would be the expected output:
if the @variable was set at 2 the output would be tFK = 2
if the @variable was set at 3 the output would be tFK = 1

Thanks

Comment: What is the output you are getting currently?

Comment: Your sample set only shows tfk 2. I'm assuming tfk is taskfk, howeverI don't understand why it would be 1 if the variable was 3. There are no 1s in your sample set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function to determine when your res is the same as the previous one for that tfk. Since we cannot use windowed functions in aggregate functions, we will make that a table variable or CTE and count the records that matched the previous tfk result.

```
DECLARE @schedule table (
id INT,
tfk INT,
scheddate DATE,
compldate DATE,
res INT
)

INSERT INTO @schedule VALUES
(1,2,'2018-02-01','2018-02-01',2),
(2,2,'2018-02-02','2018-02-02',2),
(3,2,'2018-02-03','2018-02-03',2),
(4,2,'2018-02-04','2018-02-04',3),
(5,2,'2018-02-05','2018-02-05',2),
(6,2,'2018-02-06','2018-02-06',2)

SELECT
    tfk,
    SUM(same_as_prev) AS sum_res
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        tfk,
        scheddate,
        compldate,
        res,
        CASE WHEN LAG(res) OVER (PARTITION BY tfk ORDER BY ID) = res THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS same_as_prev
    FROM @schedule
    ) tbl
WHERE scheddate between '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-22'
AND compldate IS NOT NULL
AND res = 2
GROUP BY tfk
HAVING SUM(same_as_prev) > 2
ORDER BY tfk
```

Comment: Hi, just tried this and it doesn't give the expected results. I want it to list all 'tFK' only if previous result is the same as the last one... if it does make sense...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can do something like this to count if there is already existing rows.

```
 SELECT 
 DISTINCT Count(tFK) AS [Count], tFK 
 FROM schedule
 Where res=3
 GROUP BY tFK
 HAVING Count(tFK)>0
```